# Get radiobutton value using template.find

Tags: meteor

I want to use `template.find` (in Templates.xxx.events) to get the value of the checked radiobutton of a radiobutton group. In jquery I would use `$('input:radio[name=XXXXX]:checked').val()`. That does not work with `template.find`. `template.find('input:radio[name=XXXXX]:checked')`returns null.

What should I be using as CSS selector for this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your selector looks right, so it could be just the way you are calling it. Maybe this example will help:

#### html

```
<template name="animals">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="cat">Cat<br>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="dog">Dog<br>
    <input type="button" value="Click">
  </form>
</template>
```

#### js

```
Template.animals.events({
  'click :button': function(event, template) {
    var element = template.find('input:radio[name=animal]:checked');
    console.log($(element).val());
  }
});
```

Here I'm still using jquery to extract the value, but it demonstrates the selector working.

Comment: Ok, it's working now. To be honest, I think I forgot to supply a default checked option for the radiobutton :) Thanks!